# Determine elapsed time

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, command

I am writing a C program that measures the amount of time necessary to run a command from the command line. The strategy is that fork a child process to execute the command and record a timestamp for starting time. The parent process will wait for the child process terminates and record the ending time. The elapsed time is the difference between ending time and starting time. Parent and child communicate through shared memory. However, I found that parent process does not receive starting time of child process. Is my shared memory wrong?

The code is below.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

typedef struct {
    time_t sec;
    suseconds_t msec;
} item;

item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int in = 0;
int out = 0;

int main()
{
pid_t pid;
    char *ls;
    scanf("%s", ls);

    /* fork a child process */
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
        struct timeval current;
        gettimeofday(&current, NULL);
        
        item starting_time;
        starting_time.sec = current.tv_sec;
        starting_time.msec = current.tv_usec;
        
        buffer[in] = starting_time;
        execlp(ls, "ls", NULL);
    }
    else { /* parent process */
        wait(NULL);
        
        item starting_time;
        starting_time = buffer[out];
        
        struct timeval current;
        gettimeofday(&current, NULL);
        
        long seconds = current.tv_sec - starting_time.sec;
        printf("The elapsed time is: %ld", seconds);
        
    }
}
```

Another thing is that I don't know how to run a command beside executing C program in terminal like below

```bash
./time ls
time.c
time

Elapsed time: 0.25422
```

Comment: What do you think `ls` points to?

Comment: "Is my shared memory wrong?" You do not have any shared memory. From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html): "The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces." You cannot use `buffer` to communicate between processes

Comment: @Haris I want it points to the command which is in the line "./time <command>"

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Instead copy&paste text directly into the question as formatted text. Also, how to run a program with a specific operating system is a different question that should be asked separately and it is not related to programming in general or C language specifically. Might better asked at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: That is not how command line arguments work. Some random local variable will not magically point to your arguments. And even if it would, what would `scanf` do with it then? The command line arguments to your program will be made available via arguments to `main`: `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. There are lots of questions here on SO dealing with that topic.

Comment: I read shared memory in the book "Operating System Concepts". Is there any way to communicate between parent process and child process using shared memory?

Comment: If you need to ask that question, you should read the book again. And yes, it's podsible. There are multiple ways to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
...
pid = fork();
```

That's not shared memory. Fork will create new process with a copy of everything, the copied buffer is independent of the old one, changes do not propagate.

Have some random intro about shared memory I found: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inter_process_communication/inter_process_communication_shared_memory.htm

or including fork: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-memory-shared-bw-processes-created-using/

Fortunately you don't really need shared memory for this, just measure the starting time before calling fork.

```
struct timeval starting_time;
gettimeofday(&starting_time, NULL);
pid = fork();
 
if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
    execlp(ls, "ls", NULL);
}
else { /* parent process */
    wait(NULL);
            
    struct timeval current;
    gettimeofday(&current, NULL);
    
    long seconds = current.tv_sec - starting_time.sec;
    printf("The elapsed time is: %ld", seconds);
    
}
```